# How to solve The opening PHP tag must be the first content in the file coding standard error

Tags: php, coding-style, phpcodesniffer

Error .
**The opening PHP tag must be the first content in the file**

My file code

**FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE**

[image]

code here

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("");
```

Comment: Post code instead of image or with image.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu added the code

Comment: It looks like you're already doing what the message says. Maybe you have an invisible character before it, like BOM?

Comment: What IDE are you using that's showing this warning?

Comment: @Barmar but when i do this `<?php$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("");`  error not showing

Comment: @Barmar i showing in code sniffer i don't think it related to IDE.

Comment: Didn't know about codesniffer, you showed a screenshot from an IDE, so I assumed that was where the message was coming from.

Comment: When I copy/paste your code into a `temp.php` file and run the sniff over it, I don't get any errors. The command I used is `phpcs temp.php --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.PHP.CharacterBeforePHPOpeningTag`. I would suggest running `phpcs -vv /path/to/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php --standard=Generic --sniffs=Generic.PHP.CharacterBeforePHPOpeningTag` so you can see the tokens that come out when checking the file. Make sure the first one looks like this: `Process token [0]: T_OPEN_TAG => <?php\n`. It not, there is probably an invisible char before the open tag.

Comment: @GregSherwood it is some weird issue i have to create new file with same name the error is gone.

Comment: @QaisarSatti It would have been interesting to see the verbose output, but I'm still glad you've managed to work around it with a new file.